# Bulk register IEntityTypeConfiguration<> entity framework core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Ok, so i am using entity framework with dot net core and code first migrations. This isn't a problem as such, i just wondered if anyone had come across a better way of doing this.

Currently i have many entity type configurations like so

```
public class ExampleEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ExampleEntity>
{
   public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ExampleEntity> builder)
   {
      builder.Property(p => p.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();

      // more options here
   }
}
```

and i register them in my dbcontext like so

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

  modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ExampleEntityConfiguration());

  // lot's more configurations here
}
```

has anyone come across or know of a way to register all the `IEntityTypeConfiguration` interfaces?

It just seems like a lot of repetitive code that could be solved by getting a list of the configurations, looping over them and applying in the context. I just don't know where to start with getting a list of `IEntityTypeConfiguration` classes that exist in a particular namespace.

Any help/suggestions would be great.

Comment: You can scan through all loaded assemblies for any types that implements `IEntityTypeConfiguration`. Something like: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsClass && typeof(IEntityTypeConfiguration<>).IsAssignableFrom(t)))`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It can be done with reflection like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);    
    // get ApplyConfiguration method with reflection
    var applyGenericMethod = typeof(ModelBuilder).GetMethod("ApplyConfiguration", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);            
    // replace GetExecutingAssembly with assembly where your configurations are if necessary
    foreach (var type in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
        .Where(c => c.IsClass && !c.IsAbstract && !c.ContainsGenericParameters)) 
    {
        // use type.Namespace to filter by namespace if necessary
        foreach (var iface in type.GetInterfaces()) {
            // if type implements interface IEntityTypeConfiguration<SomeEntity>
            if (iface.IsConstructedGenericType && iface.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEntityTypeConfiguration<>)) {
                // make concrete ApplyConfiguration<SomeEntity> method
                var applyConcreteMethod = applyGenericMethod.MakeGenericMethod(iface.GenericTypeArguments[0]);
                // and invoke that with fresh instance of your configuration type
                applyConcreteMethod.Invoke(modelBuilder, new object[] {Activator.CreateInstance(type)});
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tested this in my application and can confirm its working. Thank you very much for the speedy response!

Comment: They added overloads to this so there are two methods matching the name.  I modified the first line to make this work: `var applyGenericMethod = typeof(ModelBuilder).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == "ApplyConfiguration" 
            && m.GetParameters().First().ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEntityTypeConfiguration<>).GetGenericTypeDefinition()).FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 50):

Using EF Core 2.2+, it got much simpler:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   Assembly assemblyWithConfigurations = GetType().Assembly; //get whatever assembly you want
   modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(assemblyWithConfigurations);
}
```

Comment: In which package is this method defined? I have installed `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.1.1` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory 2.1.1` and this method is not exist.

Comment: @Mahmoud Which method do you mean? `ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly` or `OnModelCreating`?

Comment: I was talking about `ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly ` obviously.

Comment: @Mahmoud sorry, I made a mistake typing required version number of EF Core. EF Core 2.2+ is required.

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense. Because I have EF Core 2.1 and couldn't find that method. Thanks for modifying your answer

Comment: This is absolutely the most simple and best solution. _However_, it does not account for the case when you have more than one DbContext. In that case it is better to be able to specify which namespace, as in the solution by @paul-van-bladel

Comment: My configurations were not being loaded but I did not notice because it was falling back to Convention over Configuration which luckily I was following... took me 4 months to notice, this line helped ensure they were loaded, what an idiot I am

Comment: @JanPalas Can you estimate whether this approach has any performance downsides in comparison to applying IEntityTypeConfiguration s directly?

Comment: @JulienAmbos Haven't tested the performance. However, for me it has a great advantage that developers do not forget to register a new `IEntityConfiguration` in `OnModelCreating` whenever they add a new entity to a data model.

Answer (score 14):

The nice work from @Evk kan be further encapsulated in a reusable extension method:

```
 public static class ModelBuilderExtensions
{
    public static void ApplyAllConfigurationsFromCurrentAssembly(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder, Assembly assembly, string configNamespace = "")
    {
        var applyGenericMethods = typeof(ModelBuilder).GetMethods( BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
        var applyGenericApplyConfigurationMethods = applyGenericMethods.Where(m => m.IsGenericMethod && m.Name.Equals("ApplyConfiguration", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        var applyGenericMethod = applyGenericApplyConfigurationMethods.Where(m=>m.GetParameters().FirstOrDefault().ParameterType.Name== "IEntityTypeConfiguration`1").FirstOrDefault();


        var applicableTypes = assembly
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(c => c.IsClass && !c.IsAbstract && !c.ContainsGenericParameters);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(configNamespace))
        {
            applicableTypes = applicableTypes.Where(c => c.Namespace == configNamespace);
        }

        foreach (var type in applicableTypes)
        {
            foreach (var iface in type.GetInterfaces())
            {
                // if type implements interface IEntityTypeConfiguration<SomeEntity>
                if (iface.IsConstructedGenericType && iface.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEntityTypeConfiguration<>))
                {
                    // make concrete ApplyConfiguration<SomeEntity> method
                    var applyConcreteMethod = applyGenericMethod.MakeGenericMethod(iface.GenericTypeArguments[0]);
                    // and invoke that with fresh instance of your configuration type
                    applyConcreteMethod.Invoke(modelBuilder, new object[] { Activator.CreateInstance(type) });
                    Console.WriteLine("applied model " + type.Name);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And can be called as such:

```
public class ApiDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public ApiDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApiDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.ApplyAllConfigurationsFromCurrentAssembly("MyRoot.Api.Entities.Configuration");
    }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: When using .net core 2.1, you will need a slight adaptation in the extension method. I updated the code.

Comment: This should be the accepted solution. Very nice with being able to specify the namespace, as that would be a necessity when using multiple DbContext.

Comment: Best answer in my opinion. I did have to modify the calling line a bit though. Instead of: modelBuilder.ApplyAllConfigurationsFromCurrentAssembly("MyRoot.Api.Entities.Configuration"); I had to use: modelBuilder.ApplyAllConfigurationsFromCurrentAssembly(Assembly.GetExectuingAssembly(), "MyRoot.Api.Entities.Configuration");

Answer (score 8):

Answer from @Evk is a bit outdated and does not work any more, answer from @paul van bladel is the working one, though it contains hardcoded strings, I have utmost hatered for. In case someone shares my feeling I would like to propose my solution in form of creating static extension method:

```
public static ModelBuilder ApplyAllConfigurationsFromAssembly(
    this ModelBuilder modelBuilder, Assembly assembly)
{   
    var applyGenericMethod = typeof(ModelBuilder)
        .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
        .Single(m => m.Name == nameof(ModelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration)
            && m.GetParameters().Count() == 1
            && m.GetParameters().Single().ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEntityTypeConfiguration<>));        
    foreach (var type in assembly.GetTypes()
        .Where(c => c.IsClass && !c.IsAbstract && !c.ContainsGenericParameters)) 
    {
        foreach (var iface in type.GetInterfaces())
        {
            if (iface.IsConstructedGenericType && iface.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEntityTypeConfiguration<>)) 
            {
                var applyConcreteMethod = applyGenericMethod.MakeGenericMethod(iface.GenericTypeArguments[0]);
                applyConcreteMethod.Invoke(modelBuilder, new object[] {Activator.CreateInstance(type)});
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And, if your configuration classes are stored in the same assembly as your DbContext you use this method as follows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.ApplyAllConfigurationsFromAssembly(GetType().Assembly);           
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. one thing I noticed: you are passing the assembly as argument to `ApplyAllConfigurationsFromAssembly` but not using it; instead you are calling `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` maybe you want to correct that?

Comment: @B12Toaster Ineed! Thank you for the valid input!

Comment: Your solution cannot compile at the moment. base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);    cannot work in an Extension method because it is a static class. There is also a ; on line 6 which prevents ".Single" being called.

Comment: @Martijn Thank you very much for that valid remarks! I incorporated them into answer.

Answer (score 6):

-- DbContext

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I really like the answer @paul van bladel provided for moving the code to an extension method. I also have need to call this from other assemblies, so I created an enum and changed the applicableTypes to be set differently.

```
IEnumerable<Type> assemblyTypeList;

switch (pAssemblyMethodType)
{
    case AssemblyMethodType.CallingAssembly:
        assemblyTypeList = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(c => c.IsClass
                && !c.IsAbstract
                && !c.ContainsGenericParameters);
        break;
    case AssemblyMethodType.ExecutingAssembly:
        assemblyTypeList = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(c => c.IsClass
                && !c.IsAbstract
                && !c.ContainsGenericParameters);
        break;
    default:
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(pAssemblyMethodType), pAssemblyMethodType, null);
}
```