# Better way of registering Entities Configuration

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I have got the following code

```
   //Entities Configurations
            new OrderItemDetailPaxMap().Configure(modelBuilder.Entity<OrderItemDetailPax>());
            new ProductTermsOfServicesMap().Configure(modelBuilder.Entity<ProductTermsOfService>());
            new ProductLegalTermsAcceptedMap().Configure(modelBuilder.Entity<ProductLegalTermsAccepted>());
            
            new ProductInventoryMap().Configure(modelBuilder.Entity<ProductInventory>());
            new ProductInventoryAttributeMappingMap()
                .Configure(modelBuilder.Entity<ProductInventoryAttributeMapping>());
            new ProductInventorySpecificationAttributeMap()
                .Configure(modelBuilder.Entity<ProductInventorySpecificationAttribute>());
            new DestinationMap().Configure(modelBuilder.Entity<Destination>());
```

Where each class is something as

```
public class OrderItemDetailPaxMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<OrderItemDetailPax>
{
    //Entity Configurations 
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<OrderItemDetailPax> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(o => o.Id);
        builder.Property(o => o.FirstName).HasMaxLength(50);
        builder.Property(o => o.LastName).HasMaxLength(50);
        builder.HasOne(o => o.OrderItemDetail)
            .WithMany(o => o.OrderItemDetailPaxs)
            .HasPrincipalKey(o => o.Id)
            .HasForeignKey(o => o.OrderItemDetailId);
    }
}
```

I was wondering if there's a better way of registering them instead of doing new()....

Comment: Take a look to the method [ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.modelbuilder.applyconfigurationsfromassembly?view=efcore-7.0) that will automatically discover all the configuration in an assembly and will register them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bulk register IEntityTypeConfiguration<> entity framework core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47013752/bulk-register-ientitytypeconfiguration-entity-framework-core)